# Who do I contact to get this transcript?

Tags: pacer

I want to read a particular trial transcript from [*Jones v. Desantis*](https://www.courtlistener.com/docket/15867552/jones-v-desantis/), which was a recent case concerning the re-enfranchisement of Florida felons.

[PACER link](https://ecf.flnd.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/DktRpt.pl?106435)

I have a PACER account and I think I've located the document I want. (ECF #402).  The docket report says:

> Transcript may be viewed at the court public terminal or purchased through the Court Reporter/Transcriber before the deadline for Release of Transcript Restriction. After that date it may be obtained through PACER.  …
> Release of Transcript Restriction set for **8/6/2020**.

When I clicked through last month to download the transcript, I got [a page with the same message](https://ecf.flnd.uscourts.gov/doc1/04916726460).

But it's now 8/18 and I still get the same page with the same message.

Why isn't the transcript available?  Can I do anything about this?  Did the clerk drop the ball, or am I just waiting for the released document to make its way into PACER?

Comment: I... don't think this is a question of law per see, but... close enough about obtaining the court documents, which is fine.

Comment: I agree it's not a question of law, and I'll understand if readers want to close it as off-topic.  But it is a question that the site's membership is qualified to answer, and I don't know where would be a better place to ask.  (If anyone has a suggestion, I'll be grateful to hear it.)

Comment: It's clearly on topic, because it is about the administrative side of Courts. I meant it as a deterrent to "off topic" votes.

Comment: I'm no expert here, but I think your theory that a clerk dropped the ball is probably the right one. Try calling the filing clerk for the case?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: The message in PACER includes the name and phone number of the court reporter; I called the number and got the reporter's email address.  I've sent email and will see what happens next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted the court reporter. She did not know why the transcript was unavailable or when it would become available.   But although her price for transcripts was usually much (9×) higher, she offered to send me a copy if I paid her what PACER would have charged, had it been available there.

I waited a few weeks to see if the transcript would appear.  When it did not, rather than spend time pursuing the court clerk (which I didn't know how to do anyway) I paid the reporter for the transcript.

Comment: At times, the people that need to maintain PACER might be overwhelmed. Good that you found a way that worked.